"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" is thrown when I run a function to check the neighbors of a point on a 2d list
I have recently challenged myself to code the Depth First Search algorithm for maze generation with only a description. I have seemed to hit a roadblock in which my function for checking previous positions for empty neighbors until one is found and the position is promptly returned.
in this situation which I have manually set up is suposed to retun the position [0,2] which is the only correct answer. However, it keeps throwing me the error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" which I don't even know where to start when it comes to  fixing
def CheckIterationDepthRetreat(map,priorPoses):
    posesToSearch = priorPoses.reverse()
    for poses in posesToSearch:
        print((priorPoses[poses][0],priorPoses[poses][1]))
        if CheckNeighbors(map,posesToSearch[poses][0],posesToSearch[poses][1]) == []:
            pass
        else:
            return posesToSearch[poses]
            break

testMap = [[2,5,0,0],[0,12,0,0],[0,9,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
testPriorPoses = [[0,0],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[0,2],[0,1]]

print(CheckIterationDepthRetreat(testMap,testPriorPoses))

Any tips or tricks to figuring this out would be a huge help to getting this finished, I just don't want the whole algorith spoiled for me, this is a project to improve my skills.

The reverse() method modifies the list in place, it doesn't return a new list.
